# I have shoulder pads which is combined with the shoulder and can't figure out how should I weight this due to random vertices

Tags: mesh, weight-painting

So I have this shoulder with shoulder pads joined, Using retopology should I separate a base mesh and then the armor?, Because if I weight this I will get a bad result, any tip of this one or maybe what do you guys do when creating a base mesh then adding an armor.
[image]

Comment: Armor and body should be separate objects. It will easen all the tasks - modeling (no reason to adjust topology to armor), sculpting (no reason to create additional creases on armor/body joint), retopology, (same as modeling) and probably rigging as well. On your screenshot topology of the base mesh In the shoulder area won't work for anything like animation and maybe even for rendering as well because of Ngons and borken edge loops. Try separating armor details from body.

Comment: @MrZak thanks man I'll fix this right away, last question If I will make a high poly sculpt of a warrior should I finish the whole body or sculpt by parts helmet, shoulder pads pants etc. I'm kinda having problems with normal map in unity.

Comment: If your question is should you model high poly of a warrior body then most likely yes. It's done just in another way generally - model base mesh with good topology, it'll be body. Then select its parts where helmet/gloves/whatever will be, duplicate into another object, sculpt as needed. Once you have all them done it'll be highpoly warrior.